# '<' in Perl substitution REPLACE field

Tags: perl, substitution

Why does applying the perl code

```
 undef $/;  # read in entire file or STDIN
 $_ = <>;
 s|<head>.*<\head>|<head>...</head>|s;
```

applied to a text file containing

```
 <head>[anything]</head>
```

produce

```
 ...
```

and not

```
 <head>...</head>
```

?

When the '<' characters in the substitution REPLACE field are omitted, as in

```
 s|<head>.*</head>|head>.../head>|s;
```

the substitution produces

```
 head>...end>
```

The '<' character makes the difference, but I can find no explanation of why.

How does one produce a '<' in the substitution result?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your original code has a bug in it, `s|<head>.*<\head>|`. Note the `\h` instead of `/h`. `\h` is matches "horizontal whitespace". Is this your real code? Or did you make a mistake pasting it in? Otherwise `s|<head>.*</head>|<head>...</head>|s;` is fine, though [you should not use regexes to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Assuming `<\head>` is a mistake, your code does what you expect. Whatever you are using to view the result is probably the cause of your missing tags. Are you looking at the output in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet does not produce the output you claim it does.

```
$ perl -e'$_ = "<head>foo</head>"; s|<head>.*<\head>|<head>...</head>|s; CORE::say'
<head>foo</head>
```

The reason it doesn't perform a replacement is because `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace character.

You probably meant to use `</head>` instead of `<\head>`. That produces the desired output.

```
$ perl -e'$_ = "<head>foo</head>"; s|<head>.*</head>|<head>...</head>|s; CORE::say'
<head>...</head>
```

Nothing even similar to your code produces just `...` as you claim. Of course, if you view a file containing `<head>...</head>` in an HTML viewer, it would appear as `...`. To produces HTML that renders as `<head>...</head>`, you'll need to perform some escaping.

```
$ perl -e'
   use HTML::Escape qw( escape_html );
   $_ = "<head>foo</head>";
   s|<head>.*</head>|<head>...</head>|s;
   CORE::say(escape_html($_));
'
&lt;head&gt;...&lt;/head&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<\head>` is a mistake, your code does what you expect. Whatever you are using to view the result is probably the cause of your missing tags. Are you looking at the output in a browser?

When you remove the opening `<`, the tags no longer look like tags and they are displayed instead of being actioned.